# Replacing every letter in a given string with the letter following in the alphabet

Tags: ruby, string

I have to replace every letter in a string with the letter following it in the alphabet (i.e. `c` becomes `d`, `z` becomes `a`), capitalize every vowel (`a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`), and return the modified string. I'm trying to find solutions without calling any functions like `sort` or `find`.

I have this:

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  Changed_Letter = ""
  alphabet = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]
  for i in 0..str.length do 
    if str[i] == 
    str[i] = alphabet[i] + 1 
  return str 
end
```

but I am lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: jtbandes how did you put my answer in a nice grey square like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We expect more information: Describe what you expect the output to be, and what it currently is. What problems have you encountered? Your code isn't syntactically correct, so you should work on that first. Once your code is accepted by the Ruby interpreter as syntactically correct then you'll be in a better place to ask a question.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to avoid using `find` and `sort`? To reinvent well-tested and optimized wheels? While that's a great idea, it's not practical when you're first learning to program. Knowing the algorithms is very useful, but I'd recommend learning to use the existing tools, and over time you'll gain knowledge of how those are built and can try building your own. However, *always* be mindful of the need to use the existing wheels/methods/functions code as its been written and optimized over many years, to deal with problems you won't anticipate.

Comment: Good afternoon my fellow programmer. First and foremost thank you for guiding me in this process. As you probably noticed, I don't even know how to ask a question. That's how lost I am :)

Comment: I am trying to turn a word into a new word replacing each letter by the following letter in the alphabet. (for example: abc -> bcd)

Answer (score 2):

You are being asked to "map" each letter of the alphabet to another letter, so you will want to use the method [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

```
VOWELS = "aeiou"
letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
       "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]                    
letters.map do |c|
  <code referencing c>
end
  #=> ['b', 'c', 'd', 'E', 'f',..., 'z', 'A]
```

Now let's fill in the code, using the methods:

- [String#succ](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-succ), which, given a character, returns the character with the next-higher ASCII value. For example, `"b".ord #=> 98`, so `"b".succ #=> "c"`, since `"c".ord #=> 99`. Since `"z".succ #=> 'aa'`, we need to treat "z" as a special case. `String#succ` is the same as [String#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-next).
- [String#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F), which, given a string, returns `true` or `false` depending on whether `include?`'s argument (a string) is included in the receiver. For example, `"cat".include?("at") #=> true; "cat".include?("a") #=> true; "cat".include?("z") #=> false`. Note that `VOWELS`, since it begins with a capital letter, is a constant.
- [String#upcase](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-upcase), which converts all lowercase letters in a given string to upper case (and leaves all other characters unchanged).

```
letters.map do |c|
  if c == 'z'
    'A'
  else
    s = c.succ
    if VOWELS.include?(s)
      s.upcase
    else
      s
    end
  end
end
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "E", "f", "g", "h", "I", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
  #    "O", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "U", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A"]
```

You could instead write this using a `case` statement and Ruby's [ternary operator](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/ruby/examples-ruby-ternary-operator-true-false-syntax):

```
letters.map do |c|
  case c
  when 'z'
    'A'
  else
    s = c.succ
    VOWELS.include?(s) ? s.upcase : s
  end
end
```

or you could make use of the methods [String#ord](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ord) and [Integer#chr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
letters.map do |c|
  s = ('a'.ord + ((c.ord-'a'.ord+1) % 26)).chr
  VOWELS.include?(s) ? s.upcase : s
  end
end
```

If, for example, `c = 'r'`

```
('a'.ord + ((c.ord-'a'.ord+1) % 26).chr
#=> (97 + ((114-97+1) % 26).chr
#=> (97 + 18 % 26).chr
#=> (97 + 18).chr
#=> 115.chr
#=> 's'
```

If, however, `c = 'z'`

```
('a'.ord + ((c.ord-'a'.ord+1) % 26).chr
#=> (97 + ((122-97+1) % 26).chr
#=> (97 + 26 % 26).chr
#=> (97 + 0).chr
#=> 97.chr
#=> 'a'
```

One more way. (You can figure out why this works.)

```
letters.map do |c|
  s = c.succ[0]
  VOWELS.include?(s) ? s.upcase : s
end
```

You might instead wish to create a hash.

```
letter_mapping = {}
letters.each do |c|
  s = c.succ[0]
  letter_mapping[c] = VOWELS.include?(s) ? s.upcase : s
end
letter_mapping
  #=> { "a"=>"b", "b"=>"c", "c"=>"d", "d"=>"E", "e"=>"f", "f"=>"g", "g"=>"h", 
  #     "h"=>"I", "i"=>"j", "j"=>"k", "k"=>"l", "l"=>"m", "m"=>"n", "n"=>"O",
  #     "o"=>"p", "p"=>"q", "q"=>"r", "r"=>"s", "s"=>"t", "t"=>"U", "u"=>"v", 
  #     "v"=>"w", "w"=>"x", "x"=>"y", "y"=>"z", "z"=>"A"}
```

so, for example, `letter_mapping['r'] #=> "s"`.

In time you will find that the Ruby way of writing this is:

```
letters.each_with_object({}) do |c, letter_mapping|
  s = c.succ[0]
  letter_mapping[c] = VOWELS.include?(s) ? s.upcase : s
end
  #=> { "a"=>"b", ... "z"=>"A"}
```

One last thing. `Enumerable#map` is an instance method for every class that includes the `Enumerable` module. One such class is `Array`:

```
Array.included_modules
  #=> [Enumerable, Kernel] 
Array.instance_methods.include?(:map)
  #=> true
```

`Array` has use of all of the module `Enumerable`'s methods, *just as though they had been defined in `Array`*. That's why `map` works when the receiver is an array.

Another class that includes `Enumerable` is [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html):

```
Range.included_modules
  #=> [Enumerable, Kernel] 
Range.instance_methods.include?(:map)
  #=> true
```

Therefore, instead of writing:

```
letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
```

we could (should) write:

```
letters = ('a'..'z')
```

and all the above code would work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, it will replace a letter with its following letter also it will capitalize vowels.

```
def letter_changes(str)
  alphabets = ('a'..'z').to_a
  vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

  for i in 0..(str.length-1) do
    index = (alphabets.index(str[i]) == (alphabets.size - 1) ? 0 : (alphabets.index(str[i]) + 1))
    str[i] = alphabets[index]
    str[i] = str[i].upcase if vowels.include?(str[i])
  end
  puts str
end

## call function
letter_changes("cadcarz")

## OUTPUT
dbEdbsA
```

Comment: If you're going to give ruby advice, do it right. 1. Naming convention not corrected. 2. `each`/`each_with_index` should be preferred over `for`. 3. Unnecessary destructive `upcase!`

Comment: Also that ternary operator can be replaced with a simple `%` operator.